# Extract top 10 news from google news

Tags: google-news

I am trying to extract top N (say 10) results from a google news(http://news.google.com/) by taking an query as input, but couldn't do so. Google doesn't allow to query server through scripts. I looked at google news api, but what i understood from there is that, it allows us to display "google news results" in our website according to some query. I want to extract the news or say the hyperlinks pointing to the news.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull a feed of news based on a query by using this url

http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=usa&hl=en&q=**yoursearchterm**&cf=all&output=rss

This will allow you to get an rss feed which can then be parsed and used by your application. While this is possible I would check the small print on Google's website as I think there are restrictions as to what you can do with this data.
You would certainly have to give credit to Google and the news sources wherever you used the info.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply,
i am not able to query google server at all, this is code that i am using http://pastebin.com/WxqT61xj,
sorry if this is very naive

Comment: Hi,I tried your program and it fetches the news fine. The problem is that you need to parse the RSS properly in order to extract the fields that you require and then write them to the file. I haven't done much Java programming so unfortunately I can't help you much more but google 'java rss parser' and see what come up

Comment: This service has count filtering ,Please use this API from Rapid API https://rapidapi.com/anju.313/api/google-trends